# Vue.js component library that depends on Vuetify. $attrs is readonly - error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, vue-cli-4

**Intro**: I've generated two projects with vue-cli ~4.2.0:

- **parent-app** - main project
- **dummylib** - library which is imported by parent-app. Has a bunch of .vue components inside.
  I want to use vuetify here

Example of library component, where i utilize `<v-btn>`:

```
    <script>
    import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
    import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib'

    export default {
      name: 'DummyButton',

      components: {
        VBtn
      },

      computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
          'counter'
        ]),

        text () {
          return `I have been clicked ${this.counter}`
        }
      },

      methods: {
        ...mapActions([
          'increment'
        ])
      }
    }
    </script>

    <template>
      <v-btn color='primary' @click="increment">{{ text }}</v-btn>
    </template>
```

**Problem**: `<v-btn>` renders, but on each click i get errors in console:

- `[Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.`
- `[Vue warn]: $listeners is readonly.`

Library's **vue.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? {
        externals: {
          'vuetify/lib': 'vuetify/lib'
        }
      }
      : {}),

    resolve: {
      alias: {
        vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Having exactly the same problem...
I'm following !

Comment: @JohnnyDriesen, Unfortunately, this problem is still unresolved. I, personally, don't have any solution, except trying to avoid making library that depends on vuetify.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this resolved?

Comment: @Simon

Unfortunately, no. Maybe, it's gonna be fixed in vuetify v3...

Comment: Hi, I'm the same problem as you... Do you found a solution?

Comment: @SaveriuCIANELLI, no, haven't found any. If you solve this, please, let me know!

Comment: I have same problem, you can see this [solution](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/discussions/4068#discussioncomment-24984) and it work for me.